# Extracting isosurface from a vtkImageData

Tags: python, plot, vtk, isosurface

I am trying to create an isosurface plot from a vtkImageData. I have a numpy array which has the scalar fields. I kept the scalar field as 0 and 1 for testing. Given below is my pipeline:

```
import vtk
from vtk.util import numpy_support
import numpy as np

# Load scalar data from npy file
scalars=np.load("Scalar.npy")

# Convert numpy array to vtk
scalars=numpy_support.numpy_to_vtk(scalars)
scalars.SetName("Scalar")

# Create a vtkImageData 
grid =vtk.vtkImageData()
grid.SetDimensions(251, 251, 101)
grid.SetSpacing(0.1, 0.1, 0.25)
grid.SetOrigin(0,0,0)

# Add scalar field to the ImageData
grid.GetPointData().SetScalars(scalars)

# Get Isosurface using contour filter
contourFilter = vtk.vtkContourFilter()
contourFilter.SetInputData(grid)
contourFilter.SetArrayComponent (0)
contourFilter.SetValue(0, 1)
contourFilter.Update()
outData=contourFilter.GetOutput()
```

However, I am unable to get the isosurface from the contour filter. The number of points in outData `outData.GetNumberOfPoints()` is giving 0. However, I have value 1 at 211573 places. `np.count_nonzero(scalars[scalars==1])` gives 211573. I have saved the numpy array used in the above code [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/a5560af1a8fea58d488955a15349cfb520230119142404/1ca6bc).

Please help me to solve this issue and understand what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Try setting the contourFilter to 0.5.  You really want a contour that is between 0 and 1.  Contouring on a binary image is rather ill defined.

Comment: Hi @DaveChen, setting contourFilter to 0.5 is giving result, but not as I expected. "Contouring on a binary image is rather ill defined": I don't know. I am new to vtk. In the above example, I have created a grid in x,y,z of size 25,25,25 with a grid spacing (dx,dy,dz) of 0.1,.01,0.25. I have assigned value 1 for points which will lie inside a sphere of radius 5 centred at 12.5,12.5,12.5. So from the above example, my intention is to extract the isosurface from the data (in this case it will be a sphere). Can you guide me on the best way to perform this? Thank you.